# HTML Input with comma doesnt add to decimal in my LocalDB

Tags: html, sql, asp.net-core, razor-pages, localdb

So, my problem is, that I want to Input a Number with 2 decimals (as a currency) via HTML, I already have the right validation and all but when I import it into the Database the Comma is gone and is now behind the number with, 00

Required]

```
public decimal Budget_pp { get; set; }
```

That's how I told my Database to behave.

and then I Input Numbers via HTML in this form

```
input asp-for="Anfrage.Budget_pp" class="form-control" required placeholder="0,00" type="number" step="0.01"
```

but when I, for example, put 50,25 in my HTML form it ends up as 5025,00 in my Database

Comment: you need to configure your app to run as the specific culture that uses comma as decimal separator. If you have not configured it then the default will be en-US which does not recognize comma as a decimal separator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#localization-middleware

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is but first try it dot (.) not comma (,). It  might be related to your culture settings. If it saves it correct change your culture settings. If it doesn't work look into string format after [Required] paste 
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]

Comment: How did you achieve the client side entering `50,25` for decimal? Are your system culture is with decimal separator `,`?